# unable to install RPostgreSQL in rstudio-server docker container to connect to postgres

Tags: r, postgresql, rstudio-server, rpostgresql

I have a `rstudio-server` docker container (R-server) and a `postgres` docker container (Pg), and am using `rstudio-server` to connect to postgres database via `RPostgreSQL` package. However, I can't install `RPostgreSQL` package on R-server, and don't want to install a postgres db on R either. Is there any method to solve the problem?

The error message of installing RPostgreSQL is

```
"libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory"
```

and I think this is due to I have no postgres installed on R-server. I tried to install `libqp-dev` and a lot of depending error occurs.

Can anyone give me simple solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

had the same issue, just need to install. Found it [here](https://github.com/PecanProject/pecan/issues/131), towards the end.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```